# How to identify an user in salesforce stackexchange is a moderator or ordinary user?

Tags: discussion, moderators

How to identify an user in salesforce stackexchange is a moderator or ordinary user? Is getting reputation more than or equal to 2000 would make them as a moderator?

Thanks,

Comment: Nearly everything and anything you'd want to know about moderators can be found in this Help section: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators which includes links to the profiles of our own mods, their elevated powers and other related info on stackexchange moderation such as the *moderator agreement* and *A Theory of Moderation*. Interesting reading if you're inclined to learn more.

Comment: Thanks @crmprogdev. I would give a read on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moderators have a unique diamond mark near their name <<--

For now, we are three. We weren't selected in an election, we were requested as the first few during the beginning of the Beta phase in order to assist and bring it to where we are today.

And I think we did a HELL GOOD JOB !!!!

https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators

Comment: Thanks Saariko.